# Search for a value in an object array. (vanilla Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects(about 10 objects) with 2 properties having their respective values.

I want to check if another value of the same property exists or not.

How can i do that ?

For example

```
array = [{'family':'Roboto', 'type': 'Google'}, ......]
```

I want to search 'Roboto'. How do i do ?

**EDIT:-**
I am using Google Fonts API to get all the Google fonts into a single array. I have succeeded in that. [Codepen](http://codepen.io/sirbence/pen/mmGGzO?editors=0010). I store an array with the 'family' and 'url' of each font.

Now i want the user to search for a font. If the font is found, do something, else "Font not found"

How can i acheive this ?

**Note:-** 
A solution provided would be helpful.

Comment: Use [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Use [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find all appearance use: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

If you want to find the first appearance use: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: Neither of them does "*check if another value of the same property exists or not*"

Comment: I don't understand you? For example if he filter and his callback return an entry another value is found with this property. Or do I understand something wrong?

Comment: "check" and "or not" implies that he's looking for a boolean result value

Comment: Ok sorry, I didn't know of the existence of your function. :) I would just checking the length of the resulting array. But yours are nice to know. Thanks for that!

Answer (score -1):

That object is in the array, so `array[0].family` will return `Roboto`. or Just Declare the array like this: `array = Object{..}`. maybe I think `array = array[0]; console.log(array.familly)` will works too.